# Applying a function to every row in a dataframe column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a text based column in a dataframe similar to the following format:

```
  Text
0 I am me
1 I am not you
2 I will be him
```

with which I am trying to run a string function to remove anything after the last space (including the space). For example 'I am me' would become 'I am'

Code:

```
df['Text'] = df['Test'].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(' ').str[:-1].str.join(' '))
```

However, this gives the error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Which I am not quite understanding as the apply function works on its own, it only seems to fail when applying it to a specific column in a dataframe? (As strange and as wrong as I may be...)

Comment: `df['Text'].str.split().str[:-1].str.join(' ')`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're working with vanilla strings, you call the functions *directly*. When working with pandas columns directly, use the `str` accessor methods.

**Case 1**
As mentioned in my comment, use the `str` methods:

```
df

            Text
0        I am me
1   I am not you
2  I will be him    

df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.split().str[:-1].str.join(' ')

        Text
0       I am
1   I am not
2  I will be
```

---

**Case 2**
Alternatively, when working with `apply` on a single column, the `lambda` receives a *string*, (not a `pd.Series`), so `.str` accessor methods aren't involved.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Would you mind giving an example for Case 2 in code? As I feel I did what you explained, but I clearly haven't. Already marked as answer, so thanks.

Comment: @CuriousStudent I am going to credit @jezrael with providing you the solution to that, and I didn't want to _copy_ that. Basically see `df['Text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split(' ')[:-1]))` in his answer where he uses `x.foo` and not `x.str.foo`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Both very helpful - would be nice not to have conflict next time.

Comment: Curious why `.str[:-1]` works as intended, given that the output of `df['Text'].str.split()` is a series of lists.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want rewrite pandas string functions what are a bit slowier, but support NaNs values:

```
df['Text'] = use_data['Test'].str.split().str[:-1].str.join(' ')
```

to python string functions:

```
df['Text'] = use_data['Test'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split(' ')[:-1]))
```